# Using rank in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions, rank

With this query in postgresql

```
WITH ExtractedPosition AS (
    SELECT P.rider_id,
           P.start_date,
           P.day_index,
           P.start_hour,
           P.end_hour,
           extract(DOW FROM (P.start_date)::DATE)::INT AS position
    FROM PartTimeWorkingHourIntervals P
             JOIN Riders R ON (R.id = P.rider_id) /*Filter early, no more exist chain or where select, cuz joined*/
    WHERE (R.isAvailableForWork = TRUE and
           R.isOngoing = FALSE)
),OrderedSchedule AS (
    SELECT P1.rider_id,
           P1.start_date,
           P1.day_index,
           P1.start_hour,
           P1.end_hour,
           rank() OVER (ORDER BY (7 + P1.day_index - position) % 7) AS pos
    FROM ExtractedPosition P1
    ), SD AS (
    SELECT P2.rider_id,
           P2.start_date,
           P2.day_index,
           P2.start_hour,
           P2.end_hour,
           P2.pos,
           rank() OVER (ORDER BY P2.pos) AS pos_t
    FROM OrderedSchedule P2
)
SELECT *
FROM SD;
```

This is the output from my IDE.
[image]

I’m trying to get the same `pos` to produce the same rank, yet it only increases by 1 for each common group. So the expected `pos_t` should look like

(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7) 
instead of

(1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9,11,11,13,13)

I can think of a tedious solution to add in more Common Table Expressions using `group by` and `joins`, but it might overcomplicate the solution
Does anyone know of any simple modification to my current query?

Comment: You are looking for `dense_rank()` rather than `rank()`

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots here for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).